# Using AJAX, can we POST to a method in a ViewComponent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a ViewComponent called `WatchList`. It's being called in a page under a route named `Request`.

This is what the URL typically looks like:

[image]

And this is how I'm setting up the ViewComponent:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("WatchList", new { requestId = Model.RequestInput?.RequestId })
```

I'm attempting to make an AJAX POST from the ViewComponent:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Request/WatchList?handler=GetMyself",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
```

But I'm running into a "XML Parsing Error: no root element found" error.

Location: http://localhost:12227/.../.../Request/WatchList?handler=GetMyself

I can't tell if I'm getting the route wrong, or if I can't call ViewComponent methods from AJAX.

Here is my structure:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You cannot post to a view component.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Oh. Well, that's a bummer. I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible, with or without a ViewComponent.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said , you can't use AJAX from the ViewComponent page to get into a method in the view component class.But you could try the following workaround which maybe you want , use the `retrun ViewComponent(" ViewComponentName",new{ paramater1,paramater2...});` in a PageHandler to call the InvokeAsync method in the ViewComponent Class.